# How do I INSERT the character "&" into a MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, insert, special-characters

I think I have seen this question before but I don't think it's answered good enough yet because I can't get it to work.

The case: 
I want to insert an URL into my MySQL database like so:

```
$url = $_POST["url"]; //$_POST["url"] = "http://example.com/?foo=1&bar=2& ...";

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table(url) values('$url')") or die ("Error: " . mysql_error());
```

Now, the URL is inserted into the database properly but when I look at it, it looks like this:

```
http://example.com/?foo=1
```

It's like the URL is cut right at the "&" character. I have tried: `mysql_real_escape_string`, `htmlspecialchars`, escaping by doing `"\"` etc. Nothing seems to work.

I have read that you might be able to do it with "SQL Plus" or something like that.

Thanks in advance.

Regards, VG

Comment: Have you tried to `echo($url)` to make sure it's what you're expecting?

Comment: out of curiosity, do you have the data set to varchar(25)?

Comment: Can you put your table definition here?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I have: varchar(225)

Comment: the question should be closed as too localized and not reproduceable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chances are the problem here is nothing to do with the database query, and more to do with how the url is passed to the page. I suspect you'll find that the URL used to load the page is something like:

```
http://mydomain.com/?url=http://example.com/?foo=1&bar=2
```

This will result in a `$_GET` that looks like this:

```
array (
  'url' => 'http://example.com/?foo=1',
  'bar' => '2'
)
```

What you need is to call page with a URL that looks more like this:

```
http://mydomain.com/?url=http://example.com/?foo=1%26bar=2
```

Note that the `&` has been encoded to `%26`. *Now* `$_GET` will look like this:

```
array (
  'url' => 'http://example.com/?foo=1&bar=2'
)
```

...and the query will work as expected.

**EDIT** I've just noticed you're using `$_POST`, but the same rules apply to the body of the request and I still think this is your problem. If you are, as I suspect, using Javascript/AJAX to call the page, you need to pass the URL string through `encodeURIComponent()`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I tried encodeURIComponent() and that worked!

Answer (score 0):

It is likely the querystring is not being passed. It looks like you are receiving it from a `FORM` post. Remember that form posts that use a method of `GET` append a querystring to pass all of the form variables, so any querystring in the action is typically ignored.

So, the first thing to do is echo the URL before you try to `INSERT` it to make sure you are getting the data you think you are.

If there are variables you need to pass with the URL, use hidden inputs for that, and a method of `GET` on the form tag, and they will get magically appended as querystring parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Right !! The problem here is nothing to do with the database query has DaveRandom said.
Just use the javascript function "encodeURIComponent()".

Answer (score -1):

Depending on what you want to do with the stored value, you also urlencode() the string: http://php.net/manual/de/function.urlencode.php

Cheers,
Max

P.S.: SQL*Plus is for Oracle Databases.

Answer (score -1):

maybe escape the url with urlencode then you can decode it if you want to pull it out of the db